# Hide bootstrap popover when click elsewhere with "data-poload"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to hide bootstrap popover whenever the user click on different button or any where else on the page. I've search a lot in this site but none of them works. Which I think mainly because I have few of these `<a data-poload='example.com' rel=popover style='text-align:right; float:right;'>Details</a>` in one page as my popover link. Please help thanks!

Example

```
<a data-poload='example.com' rel=popover style='text-align:right; float:right;'>Details</a> 
<a data-poload='example2.com' rel=popover style='text-align:right; float:right;'>Second Details</a> 
<a data-poload='example3.com' rel=popover style='text-align:right; float:right;'>Third Details</a>

table.$('*[data-poload]').bind('click', function () {
        var e = $(this);
        e.unbind('click');
        $.get(e.data('poload'), function (d) {
            e.popover({
                content: d,
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                //trigger: 'manual',
                placement: function (tip, element) {
                    var offset = $(element).offset();
                    height = $(document).outerHeight();
                    width = $(document).outerWidth();
                    vert = 0.5 * height - offset.top;
                    vertPlacement = vert > 0 ? 'bottom' : 'top';
                    horiz = 0.5 * width - offset.left;
                    horizPlacement = horiz > 0 ? 'bottom' : 'bottom';
                    placement = Math.abs(horiz) > Math.abs(vert) ? horizPlacement : vertPlacement;
                    return placement;
                }
            }).popover('show');
        });
    });
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59Dpk/3/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Hi felix, I've added the jsfiddle.. But not sure why is it not working there.. But it's working on my local computer